# Proof concerning outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that $X:=[a,b]$ is a fixed interval in $\mathbb R$ and let $m^*$ be the outer measure on $X$. Suppose that $A \subset X$ is a null set, i.e. $m^*(A)=0.$ Show that for every $B\subset X$,

$m^*(B \cup A)=m^*(B\setminus A)=m^*(B)$

I'm studying measure theory and looking for some direction on this proof. Thanks!

Comment: HINT: You will need to use monotonicity and subadditivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take my hint from above if you would like just that. Below is a more complete solution.

$m^*(B\setminus A)\leq m^*(B)$ by monotonicity. $m^*(B)\leq m^*(B\cup A)$ by the same. $m^*(B\cup A)\leq m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A)$ by subadditivity.  Hence:
$$
m^*(B\setminus A)\leq m^*(B)\leq m^*(B\cup A)\leq m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A)=m^*(B\setminus A).
$$
So all the inequalities collapse into equalities.

Answer (score -2):

$B \cup A = (B \setminus A) \cup A $, that is, it is the union of two disjoint sets so
$$m^*(B \cup A) = m^* (B \setminus A) + m^*(A)= m^*(B \setminus A). $$

Now since $A$ is a null set, $ B \setminus A= B$, hence $m^* (B \cup A)= m^*(B)$.

Comment: The outer measure of the union of two disjoint sets is not necessarily the sum of their outer measures: Take any non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ as $A$, and $[0,1]\setminus A$ as $B$ for a counterexample. To get the equality in such generality you'd need more, for example, that $A$ and $B$ are not only disjoint but a positive distance apart.

Comment: Oh, you also say that $B\setminus A=B$. This is false in general. It is true if $A$ is disjoint from $B$, but false otherwise. "Null" means "of (outer) measure $0$". It is not the same as "empty".

Comment: Then $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) - m^*(A \cap B)$ does not hold as well?